# Diff options in Unix

Tags: unix, diff

I am comprating two files containing a large array of numbers using 'diff'. The files look identical except some numbers have minus signs instead of plus signs. Is there an option to ignore a character like '-' and then compare the files?

Just to clarify:

If file 1 is :

```
1 -1 5 -3
```

and the other is

```
1 1 5 3
```

I want the return to say they are identical.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sed` to take out the `-` characters before diffing:

```
sed s/-//g f1 | diff - f2
```

Example:

```
$ cat f1
1 -1 5 -3
$ cat f2
1 1 5 3
$ sed s/-//g f1 | diff - f2
$ echo $?
0
```